# The nil check for presence of an element is not working as expected in functional test case

Tags: ios, swift, earlgrey

Suppose I am using a code snippet in `setup()` method just before running a test case like this:

```
if EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(grey_accessibilityID("TabBar-Navigation-Search")).assertWithMatcher(grey_sufficientlyVisible()) != nil {
    TabBarNavigation().navigateToSearch()
} else {
    assentViewModelsSwifts.signInCheck()
    assentViewModelsSwifts.enterLoginCredentials("username", password: "password")
    let visibleSignInButtonMatcher = grey_allOfMatchers(grey_accessibilityID("Login-Button-SignIn"), grey_sufficientlyVisible())
    EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(visibleSignInButtonMatcher).performAction(grey_tap())
    TabBarNavigation().navigateToSearch()
    Log.info("Landed on Search Page")
}
```

I am running into an error.
Assertion `'assertWithMatcher: matcherForSufficientlyVisible(>=0.750000)' was not performed because no UI element matching (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID("TabBar-Navigation-Activity"))` was found.

Actually I want to check the presence of an element. If element is present, do a certain step or do something else. But although the element is not present on that particular screen, the code inside the loop is not executed.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try below method for nil check:**

```
- (instancetype)assertWithMatcher:(id<GREYMatcher>)matcher error:(__strong NSError **)errorOrNil
```

**Try below code to check nil:**

```
let errorOrNil
EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(grey_accessibilityID("TabBar-Navigation-Search")).assertWithMatcher(grey_sufficientlyVisible(), error:&errorOrNil)
 if errorOrNil != nil {
                TabBarNavigation().navigateToSearch()
            } else {
            assentViewModelsSwifts.signInCheck()
            assentViewModelsSwifts.enterLoginCredentials("username", password: "password")
            let visibleSignInButtonMatcher = grey_allOfMatchers(grey_accessibilityID("Login-Button-SignIn"), grey_sufficientlyVisible())
            EarlGrey().selectElementWithMatcher(visibleSignInButtonMatcher).performAction(grey_tap())
            TabBarNavigation().navigateToSearch()
            Log.info("Landed on Search Page")
            }
```